# Delphi error with generics and interfaces

Tags: delphi, generics, interface

The following Delphi code does not compile with an error in Foo function, but the Foo2 function compile. It drive me crazy, does anyone have an idea ?

```
type

  IA<T> = Interface
  end;

  TA<T> = class(TInterfacedObject, IA<T>)
    function Foo<V> : IA<V>;
  end;

  TB<U,T> = class(TA<T>)
  end;

  TC = class
    function Foo2<T,V> : IA<V>;
  end;


implementation

{ TA<T> }

function TA<T>.Foo<V>: IA<V>;
begin
  Result := TB<T,V>.Create;
end;

{ TC }

function TC.Foo2<T,V>: IA<V>;
begin
  Result := TB<T,V>.Create;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does look odd, and I suspect that it is a bug. You can work around it by declaring that `TB<U, T>` implements `IA<T>`. Change

```
TB<U, T> = class(TA<T>)
```

to

```
TB<U, T> = class(TA<T>, IA<T>)
```

---

Note that your code with all the generics removed does compile:

```
type
  IA = interface
  end;

  TA = class(TInterfacedObject, IA)
    function Foo: IA;
  end;

  TB = class(TA)
  end;

  TC = class
    function Foo2: IA;
  end;

function TA.Foo: IA;
begin
  Result := TB.Create;
end;

function TC.Foo2: IA;
begin
  Result := TB.Create;
end;
```

This would appear to back up my belief that your code is correct and should be accepted by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why Foo2 does work without changing declaration ?

Comment: As I said, it looks like a bug to me

Comment: I think it is because Foo2 explicitly refers to the interface. Foo on refers indirectly via class TA, and therefore TB needs to be told that is implements the interface.

Comment: @Dsm I don't understand. The type returned by the two functions is identical, and the code in the two functions is identical.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know, but I have seen similar issues reported on this site and this has been the reason. I think it is by design, possibly safety first, If you implicitly use an interface (via inheritance) then you must declare that interface in the class that uses it.

Comment: @Dsm The non generic code in my answer provides a counter example to that claim I think.

Comment: In a way, but I think it is generics that introduce the possibility of ambiguous interfaces, and why generics are treated differently. I don't pretend to be an expert here, I am just really regurgitating what I have seen before. Perhaps with all my comments and deleted answer I should have used 'generic interface' wherever I used 'interface'.